Does every central extension come from a 2-cocycle?
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $[C]\in H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$. We can define a group $G_C\equiv G\times \mathbb{R}$ with the operation $$(f,\alpha )\cdot (g,\beta)\equiv (fg,\alpha +\beta +C(f,g)).$$ One can easily see that $G_C$ with the operation above is a group. Moreover, $G_C$ is a central extension of $G$ by $\mathbb{R}$: $$0\to \mathbb{R}\overset{i}{\to}G_C\overset{\pi}{\to}G\to 0 $$ is an exact sequance where $i(\alpha )=(e_G ,\alpha )$ and $\pi ((f,\alpha))=f$ and $\mathbb{R}\subseteq Z(G_C)$. Note that $C$ satisfies in the cocycle condition $$C(f,gh)+C(g,h)=C(fg,h)+C(f,g).$$
My question: If $H$ is a central extension of $G$ by $A$ (i.e., $0\to A\to H\to G\to 0$ is an exact sequence and $A\subseteq Z(H)$), then is there a $[C]\in H^2(G;\mathbb{R})$ such that $H= G_C$?

Did you mean cocycle in the title?

It depends on your exact setting. For Lie groups (and, more generally, topological groups) one normally uses the continuous 2nd cohomology groups (and continuous group homomorphisms).

@J.W.Tanner Sorry. I've just edit it.

@MoisheKohan You are right. I meant continuous ones.
